# How to register 'qt' graphics toolkit in GNU Octave

Tags: qt, octave

Available graphics backends (toolkits) in my 3.2.4 GNU Octave (can't update it, no root privileges) are `fltk` and `gnuplot`. I was able to include `fltk` with `backend ("fltk")`, but `qt` tookit is not supported, the command `backend ("qt")` will raise the error:

```
error: feval: function '__init_qt__' not found
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.2.4/m/plot/backend.m at line 56, column 5
```

Is it a question of installing [QtHandles](https://github.com/goffioul/QtHandles)? If so, how to proceed? Is there a simplest way to do it without root privileges?

Run on a Ubuntu 12.04-based distro.

Comment: Unfortunately build-in Qt-based backend is available only for Octave version 4.0.0 or newer.

Comment: @Dmitry: GNU Octave 3.8.x already had the Qt toolkit and the experimental GUI which had to be enabled with "--force-gui" but the 4.0 release was the first with "official" GUI and enabled per default

Comment: @nightcod3r: You can build GNU Octave from source tarball without root and install it in your home dir

Comment: @Andy, you're right, I can see it in a 3.8.1 installation of GNU Octave. Thanks for driving my focus outwards, building Octave locally is an option. Question is, how hard this might be without root privileges? I mean, to start with, you could miss the very basic development kits. I'll be happy to propose it as a question in itself, if you think that the whole process can get messy.

Comment: @nightcod3r Perhaps chroot/debootstrap might be an option of course the easiest way is to talk with your administrator and ask to update to Octave 4.2.0....

Comment: Gosh, @Andy, Linux is such a strange loop, you can hardly picture all options at once, but you're right.  As for talking to the administration, no way, it's a big institution, I better go around it.

Comment: not the most efficient solution, but as a workaround to retarded administration, if you have a windows vm you could install the latest octave there as a windows binary

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou What benefit yould he have to install GNU Octave in a MS Windoze VM and not in a GNU/Linux based VM? I can only see drawbacks

Comment: @Andy absolutely none whatsoever! I'm just guessing if he's on a linux machine in a corporate environment, there's a decent chance he has been provided with a Windows VM, so just pointing it out as a workaround.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou It's all about free software, no Windows or Mac-based product around (fortunately!). It's an academic environment (some 8K schools), controlled by an administration crew. Basically you can use what the distro includes, plus what can be installed locally.

Comment: You can bootstrap a minimal development environment in a chroot. Suppose that the place runs on CentOS 6. All you do is install a minimal CentOS 6 chroot in your user account, then install all the tools/libraries you need to build Octave.